# HighChart Skipping the first point : Highcharts, Javascript

Tags: javascript, csv, highcharts

I am trying to plot the a Highcharts data from the CSV file.
although I am able to plot the graph , but the problem is that the chart is skipping the first row value .

Here's the Code that I have tried :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$.get('abc.csv', function(data) {
var lines = data.split('\n');
console.log(lines);
var ecg=[];
$.each(lines, function(lineNo, lineContent){
if(lineNo > 0)
    {
    ecg[lineNo-1] = lineContent.split(',')[1];
    }
});
 var ecgData=[];
$.each(lines, function(lineNo, lineContent){
if(lineNo > 0)
    {
    ecgData[lineNo-1] = 
parseFloat(lineContent.substring(lineContent.lastIndexOf(",")) );
    }
});
console.log(ecg);
console.log(ecgData);
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        type: 'line'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'ECG Data'
    },
    subtitle: {
        text: ''
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: ecg,
        crosshair: false
    },
    yAxis: {
       // min: 0,
        title: {
            text: 'ECG Peaks'
        }
    },
   tooltip: {
        enable: false
    },
    plotOptions: {
        column: {
            pointPadding: 0.2,
            borderWidth: 0
        }
    },
    series: [{
        name: '',
        data: ecgData

    } ]
});
 });
 </script>
```

The CSV file contains the Following data :

```
1
4
3
9
3
4
4
6
4
5
3
4
3
3
1
3
2
3
2
3
4
4
3
3
4
```

Although I am getting the Chart as expected from the highcharts, 
But the problem is that the first point which is `1` is missing from my chart. and chart is starting directly from `4`. which is my second data.
[image]

I hope my question is clear. Any Help is appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Self explanatory. Notice the equal to or more than 0 operator

```
$.each(lines, function(lineNo, lineContent){
if(lineNo >= 0)
{
    ecg[lineNo-1] = lineContent.split(',')[1];
    }
});
```

Comment: nothing changes with that, it still shows same result.